# Display html formated table using webview in Android

Tags: android

I am trying a lot but it is not wroking. Here's my code:

```
public class SchofferStr extends Activity {

    String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menu);
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
        setContentView(webview);
        webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }

}
```

the summary string i have is a lengthy htmlformatted table. But problem is this code is not even working for this simple html formated string. What is it that im doing wrong?
Please help, im stuck.

Comment: First of all, you can't have setContentView called twice like that...

Comment: @Sephy: Of course you can. You can have as many `setContentView()` methods as you wish as the last one will simply override all the preceding ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try:

```
webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, summary, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Comment: Hi CommonsWare, I used loadDataWithBaseURL but still getting a blank output. The window appears but is totally blank as before.
It is not showing anything. In my xml layout, i have also webview tag, if that has to do anything.

What could be the reason. Is there anything else i should check??

Comment: @Rizwan: Start with this project: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/WebKit/Browser2 -- it is known to work. Then, adjust as needed.

Comment: Thankyou so much CommonsWare. I found my issue going through the example you referred me. I had to modify the AndroidManifest.xml file and add these lines to intent filter in my activity:
"android.intent.action.MAIN" & "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER".
It is working now. Thanks again, you solved my problem.